# How to make sure items stay at the same height while resizing text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

If the window resizes the text "pushes itself" and the buttons get pushed down.

The `button`s are all over the place. I want the buttons to be at the same place.

[Check external fiddle to be able to resize to desktop](http://jsfiddle.net/k2551181/8vg0u1d6/1/)

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Sure. I made a minimal version of the code : https://jsfiddle.net/8vg0u1d6/6/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: It's not very clear what effect you're after, but if you mean that you want the buttons aligned to the bottoms of the articles, just position them absolutely. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/8vg0u1d6/7/. Otherwise, please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your `button`s will place themselves in reference to text content.

EDIT: I just noticed you were using flex, so why not take advantage of it.

**Solution 1:** flexbox

**[---> JS Fiddle <---](http://jsfiddle.net/Syden/8vg0u1d6/17/)**

[image]

**Solution 2:** `min-height`

You could set a `min-height` value on `p` similar to the longest text, for example in the fiddle I used `180px`, but note you may have gaps between `button`s and text if the latter is very short and this will also vary depending on the viewport's width, since if reduced will shrink text and push it down overflowing the `min-height`, try to find a balance.

Add `min-height` to `section article p`. (adjust value to your benefit - note that `p`'s `border` was added simply as reference of the height).

**[---> JSFiddle <---](http://jsfiddle.net/Syden/8vg0u1d6/12/)**

[image]